# shortcut icon from external url

Tags: android

i want to make a shortcut from an web not from resource this code make shortcut

```
Intent shortcutIntent = getShortcutIntent();

Intent addIntent = new Intent();
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, mAppData.title);

Intent.ShortcutIconResource shortcutIconResource = Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(MainApplication.getAppContext(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);

addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, shortcutIconResource);
addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");

MainApplication.getAppContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
```

would like to load the icon from the web ?

i search before i ask here but i didn't find any answer

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but a `ShorcutIconResource` needs to point to a drawable resource, not a file or anything else.

Also, note that `INSTALL_SHORTCUT` is not supported on Android 8.0+. The replacement mechanism using `ShortcutManager` has greater flexibility in terms of where the icons come from.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question. in case someone needs it!

You can pass icon as bitmap

```
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON, bitmap);
```